# python variables: reading values from a variable in a for loop

Tags: python, gsutil

I am reading values from a `txt file` and passing them to a `for` loop inside which some processing is done on each of the value. The file contents are `GCP Storage buckets` as shown below

```
 gs://inxxxx12/
 gs://xxxxx1231/  etc
```

The values can range from 1 to more than 100 storage buckets

The `python` code is as follows

```
  import subprocess
  import json
  import shlex

  buckets = open('permissions.txt', 'r')
  for x in buckets:
    version_on = "gsutil  versioning set on x"
    version_on = shlex.split(version_on)
    project_output = subprocess.check_output(version_on)
    print project_output
```

My issue is with below line of `code` .

```
  for x in buckets:
    version_on = "gsutil  versioning set on x"
```

I am struggling to read the values of `variables x` inside the `for` loop .

Following is the error

```
['gsutil', 'versioning', 'set', 'on', 'x']
CommandException: "versioning" command does not support "file://" URLs. Did you mean to use a gs:// URL?
```

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Skip the string version of the command and the `shlex.split()`, and go directly to the list of parameters: `['gsutil', 'versioning', 'set', 'on', x]`.  Note lack of quotes around `x`.

Comment: Works! and thanks so much

Comment: @jasonharper please move your comment to an answer